# jQuery UI: Datepicker set year range dropdown to 100 years

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using the Datepicker the year drop down by default shows only 10 years. The user has to click the last year in order to get more years added.

How can we set the initial range to be 100 years so that the user will see a large list by default?

[image]

```
    function InitDatePickers() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            maxDate: '@maxDate',
            minDate: '@minDate'
        });
    }
```

Comment: @dmaij: If only a glance at the API docs wouldn't have answered it... But yes, the image is lovely... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There should be a rule that questions look like this. And indeed, looking in the api docs could have saved time to create the image..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good thing that there is a API. But I just googled "jquery datepicker year range" and found this. Answering my question in 10 seconds. Faster then using an API.

Answer (score 618, accepted):

You can set the year range using this option per documentation here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

```
yearRange: '1950:2013', // specifying a hard coded year range
```

or this way

```
yearRange: "-100:+0", // last hundred years
```

From the Docs

> Default: "c-10:c+10"
>
> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year ("-nn:+nn"), relative to the currently selected year ("c-nn:c+nn"), absolute ("nnnn:nnnn"), or combinations of these formats ("nnnn:-nn"). Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down, to restrict which dates may be selected use the minDate and/or maxDate options.

Comment: Was having trouble before i realized that the `+` sign is required.

Comment: Thanks, hard coding it this way yearRange: '1950:2013' worked

Comment: for jQuey-Ui yearRange: "c-100:+c+10" works fine where c stands for current year

Comment: @TechieBrij This is helpful but it's supposed to be `c-100:c+10`

Comment: @Obsidian `c` actually means "Current selected year" and not current year http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

Answer (score 22):

**Try the following:-**

> **ChangeYear:-** When set to true, indicates that the cells of the previous or next month indicated in the calendar of the current month
> can be selected. This option is used with options.showOtherMonths set
> to true.
>
> **YearRange:-** Specifies the range of years in the year dropdown. (Default value: “-10:+10″)

**Example:-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
        changeYear:true,
        yearRange: "2005:2015"
    });
});
```

**See:-** [set year range in jquery datepicker](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119122404/http://jqueryasp.net/set-year-range-jquery-datepicker/)

Answer (score 7):

I did this:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
var yrRange = dateToday.getFullYear() + ":" + (dateToday.getFullYear() + 50);
and then
yearRange : yrRange
```

where `50` is the range from current year.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the year range using this option in jQuery UI datepicker:

```
yearRange: "c-100:c+0", // last hundred years and current years

yearRange: "c-100:c+100", // last hundred years and future hundred years

yearRange: "c-10:c+10", // last ten years and future ten years
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to implement the datepicker to select the birthdate and I had troubles changing the `yearRange` as it doesn't seemed to work with my version (1.5). I updated to the newest jquery-ui datepicker version here: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker.

Then I found out they provide this very helpful on-the-fly tool, so you can config your whole datepicker and see what settings you have to use.

That's how I found out that the option

> defaultViewDate

is the option I was looking for and I didn't find any results searching the web.

So for other users: If you also want to provide the datepicker to change the birthdate, I suggest to use this code options:

```
$('#birthdate').datepicker({
    startView: 2,
    maxViewMode: 2,
    daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2",
    defaultViewDate: { year: new Date().getFullYear()-20, month: 01, day: 01 }
});
```

When opening the datepicker you will start with the view to select the years, 20 years ago relative to the current year.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late in the day for suggesting this, given how long ago the original question was posted, but this is what I did.

I needed a range of 70 years, which, while not as much as 100, is still too many years for the visitor to scroll through.  (jQuery does step through year in groups, but that's a pain in the patootie for most people.)

The first step was to modify the JavaScript for the datepicker widget:
Find this code in jquery-ui.js or jquery-ui-min.js (where it will be minimized):

```
for (a.yearshtml+='<select class="ui-datepicker-year" onchange="DP_jQuery_'+y+".datepicker._selectMonthYear('#"+
a.id+"', this, 'Y');\" onclick=\"DP_jQuery_"+y+".datepicker._clickMonthYear('#"+a.id+"');\">";b<=g;b++)
 a.yearshtml+='<option value="'+b+'"'+(b==c?' selected="selected"':"")+">"+b+"</option>";
a.yearshtml+="</select>";
```

And replace it with this:

```
a.yearshtml+='<select class="ui-datepicker-year" onchange="DP_jQuery_'+y+
 ".datepicker._selectMonthYear('#"+a.id+"', this, 'Y');
 \" onclick=\"DP_jQuery_"+y+".datepicker._clickMonthYear('#"+a.id+"');
 \">";
for(opg=-1;b<=g;b++) {
    a.yearshtml+=((b%10)==0 || opg==-1 ?
        (opg==1 ? (opg=0, '</optgroup>') : '')+
        (b<(g-10) ? (opg=1, '<optgroup label="'+b+' >">') : '') : '')+
        '<option value="'+b+'"'+(b==c?' selected="selected"':"")+">"+b+"</option>";
}
a.yearshtml+="</select>";
```

This surrounds the decades (except for the current) with OPTGROUP tags.

Next, add this to your CSS file:

```
.ui-datepicker OPTGROUP { font-weight:normal; }
.ui-datepicker OPTGROUP OPTION { display:none; text-align:right; }
.ui-datepicker OPTGROUP:hover OPTION { display:block; }
```

This hides the decades until the visitor mouses over the base year.  Your visitor can scroll through any number of years quickly.

Feel free to use this; just please give proper attribution in  your code.

Answer (score 0):

firstly be careful that which file is feeding your views as you know there is 2 types
of js files first of them is usual one here is bootstrap-datapicker.js and the other one which is mainly used is called bootstrap-datapicker.min.js its better to find the same parts in each file and edit it.
try this yearRange: "c-100:c+0"
if you just do this and save the file your date picker is able to pick last 100 and feature 10 years.