# Showing month and year in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I am trying to show year and month where users can select year and month as dropdown from the date-picker but my issue is that the year drop down is not showing all the years when you select it first. For example, when i select the year drop-down, it shows me the years from 2005 to 2025 in the selection.  Is there a way to show the scroll-bar when users can use the scroll-bar to go all the way back to 1950 or 1960 when i select the year dropdown?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can do that by using yearRange. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13865256/1292904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the JQuery UI documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

add `yearRange: "min:max"` to your datepicker.