# Set min/max Date of jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having trouble understanding how to set the min/max Date of the jquery Datepicker. When I check the [docs](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max), i see that the `dateformat` is expected in `new Date(2009, 1 - 1, 26)`.
What does the `1-1` mean? When I chec [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) schools for js dateformats, I cannot find this one.

So I tried

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm',
    minDate: new Date(2001-01),
    maxDate: '+15Y'
});
```

But that leaves me with completely random results... It starts 2006 and ends 2026.

Here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ANF2y/58/

[image]

Comment: In JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object `month` is calculated as 0 to 11. To set the month use `current month - 1`.

Comment: @Pugazh ok. But why is the start**date** implemented as `1-1`?!

Comment: @Stophface its month and not date. `new Date(year, month, date)`

Comment: `1 - 1` equates to `0`. So that is a valid month `0 - January`

Comment: @Pugazh so for starting on the first of januaray 2001 I would enter `new Date(2001, 00, 01)` I suppose, with `dateFormat: 'yyyy, mm, dd'`?  That leaves me with the same results. It starts 2006 and ends 2026.

Comment: Yes, `minDate: new Date(2001, 00, 01)` and date format can be of your choice Eg: `dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm'`

Comment: `maxDate: '+15Y'` means `today + 15 years`. In case today is 23-Sep-2016 maxDate will be `23-Sep-2031`.

Comment: @Pugazh check this fiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/ANF2y/58/

Comment: new Date should be of the format (year, month(0 - 11), date). Check this link for acceptable formats - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Examples

Comment: Check the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ANF2y/62/. However there is an bug with jQuery Datepicker. It's not showing the years previous to 2006 on dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript `month` is calculated from 0 to 11. So while creating a new Date use **current month - 1**.

`1 - 1` equates to `0`. So that is a valid month (`0 - January`).

In your case set `minDate` as below.

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  minDate: new Date(2001, 0, 1),
  maxDate: '+15Y',
  dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm'
});
```

> that is because the jquery date picker only shows 15 items at a time, there is no max date set so you can go as far in the future as you want. When it is set to 2001 you see 2006 in the dropdown as it is limited to 15 items. Select 2006 and then you'll see 2001 in the dropdown. Is your question can I show more items in the year dropdown list?

Comment: This one: http://jsfiddle.net/ANF2y/60/ starts at 2001 on your computer? Over here it starts 2006 and ends 2026...

Comment: It's a bug with jQuery [Datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). But you can select the previous months by using arrows :-(

Comment: I will report the bug to the developer/jQuery forum!!

Comment: oh man :( And i was freaking out over here... I thought is has something to do with the date format I am using. Thanks! I will try bootstrap-datepicker.

Comment: I dont think a bug report is necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865218/jquery-ui-datepicker-set-year-range-dropdown-to-100-years

Comment: Awesome!. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to go into minDate or maxDate as that has been well covered. But in addition to that, what you are looking for is `yearRange` will set the number of visible items in the year dropdown of the jquery date picker.

The documentation states:

> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to today's year ("-nn:+nn"), relative to the currently selected year ("c-nn:c+nn"), absolute ("nnnn:nnnn"), or combinations of these formats ("nnnn:-nn"). Note that this option only affects what appears in the drop-down.

[Reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange)